# Spark failing because "Invoking stop() from shutdown hook"

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, emr

I'm having the following problem when running Spark on AWS EMR. While doing a join on a table to filter certain IDs out, Spark suddenly dies with the stdout file reporting the following:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.execution.EvaluatePython.takeAndServe.
```

The command I'm executing where it's breaking is running fine when I run it on local mode on my machine (on a much smaller dataset), and looks like the following:

```
sampled_data = data_df \
                .join(sample_ids, data_df.entity_id == sample_ids.entity_id, 'inner') \
                .drop(data_df.entity_id) \
                .where(data_df.subcategory == 'main') \
                .select(['entity_id', 'date', 'hour', 'pageno', 'position']) \
                .dropDuplicates()

print 'sampled_data test...'
sampled_data.take(3)
```

The complete error log (stderr) can be found here: http://pastebin.com/cUrPUQcX. I've gone over it a couple of times but can't find any issue, just that suddenly this occurs, with not much information on why:

```
16/07/20 21:47:08 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Also, if I check the executor's log on the WebUI I see the following:

```
[...]
16/07/22 15:34:43 INFO s3n.S3NativeFileSystem: Opening 's3n://path/2016-07-01/data_2016-07-01T12-03-35_node7.csv' for reading
16/07/22 15:34:43 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver commanded a shutdown
16/07/22 15:34:43 INFO storage.MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/07/22 15:34:43 INFO storage.BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
16/07/22 15:34:43 INFO s3n.S3NativeFileSystem: Opening 's3n://path/2016-07-01/data_2016-07-01T12-03-36_node5.csv' for reading
16/07/22 15:34:43 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
16/07/22 15:34:43 INFO remote.RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
16/07/22 15:34:43 WARN executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: An unknown (ip-172-31-22-115.us-west-2.compute.internal:32836) driver disconnected.
16/07/22 15:34:43 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver 172.31.22.115:32836 disassociated! Shutting down.
16/07/22 15:34:43 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/07/22 15:34:43 INFO codegen.GenerateMutableProjection: Code generated in 23.143313 ms
16/07/22 15:34:43 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1469108763595_0005/spark-f9a9e3ba-1761-49d0-84b0-8711f1ca71f0
```

I'm also initializing the cluster with "spark.executor.memory": "10G", and 5 executors.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm thinking that you have a memory issue, but what type of instances are you running on? I assume the job breaks down during the join? Is the UI reporting any errors?

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt I'm running the cluster on 5 r3.xlarge machines. Yes, the job does break down on the join, and if I reduce the size of input files it does complete successfully. The UI doesn't report any errors, besides showing that the executors get removed before the task is complete. Do you have any suggestions on what parameters to tweak to solve this?

Comment: I've added the WebUI logs to the question.

Comment: Well, it looks like your driver is disconnecting, but my bet is still on a memory issue on one of the executors - probably you have a single key that takes up too much memory causing the cluster to fail during the join. Have you changed the `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead`? If not - change that. It defaults to something ridiculously low.

Comment: How do you change this parameter ?